# получаю не все данные с сервера vk api

Tags: vkontakte-api

Пользуюсь методом: wall.get.

```
import settings
import mysql.connector
import requests
from settings import access_token


database = mysql.connector.connect(user=settings.db_login, password=settings.db_password,
                                   host=settings.dp_ip, database=settings.db_name, use_unicode=True,
                                   charset='utf8', collation='utf8_general_ci', autocommit=True)

cursor = database.cursor()

member_request_params = (
    ('access_token', access_token),
    ('domain', group_name),
    ('count', 1),
    ('offset', offset),
    ('date_from', '2013-08-08'),
    ('date_to', '2018-09-08'),
    ('version', 5.74))

r = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get', params=member_request_params).json()
print(r)
return {'r': r, 'offset': offset}
```

Согласно документации

Должен получить:

```
{
"response": {
"count": 1680,
"items": [{
"id": 159112,
"from_id": -86529522,
"owner_id": -86529522,
"date": 1524496633,
"marked_as_ads": 0,
"post_type": "post",
"text": "Билеты на VK Fest 2018 подорожают уже завтра! &#128561;

Во вторник мы объявим первых артистов и участников — такое нельзя пропустить! А если вы еще не приобрели заветный тикет по самой лучшей цене, самое время сделать это прямо сейчас. Другого шанса не будет!

Сюда, сюда, сюда: vk.cc/tickets

#vkfest #vkfest2018",
"is_pinned": 1,
"attachments": [{
"type": "photo",
"photo": {
"id": 456250147,
"album_id": -7,
"owner_id": -86529522,
"user_id": 100,
"photo_75": "https://pp.userap...753/zCbp91bS050.jpg",
"photo_130": "https://pp.userap...754/_VRtP8PMGo8.jpg",
"photo_604": "https://pp.userap...755/d2rGumh5V_s.jpg",
"photo_807": "https://pp.userap...756/-0qYGixE9Ho.jpg",
"photo_1280": "https://pp.userap...757/Tmmed228FjA.jpg",
"width": 1000,
"height": 700,
"text": "",
"date": 1524496066,
"post_id": 159112,
"access_key": "86cfea245b59397984"
}
}],
"post_source": {
"type": "vk"
},
"comments": {
"count": 23,
"groups_can_post": true,
"can_post": 1
},
"likes": {
"count": 67,
"user_likes": 0,
"can_like": 1,
"can_publish": 1
},
"reposts": {
"count": 3,
"user_reposted": 0
},
"views": {
"count": 19717
}
}]
}
}
```

Проблема в том, что не получаю кол-во просмотров (`views count`)

Answer (score 0):

Вы указываете параметр **version**, а надо **v**
В итоге у вас используется старая версия API в ответе, в которой этого поля еще нет.

Comment: пробовал и так и так. Все-равно не возвращается кол-во просмотров